# Trying to visualize ML with a grad-CAM heatmap but K.gradients returning zero values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, heatmap

for visualizing the results of the ML process i decided to use a CAM heatmap.
I used the code provided [here](https://github.com/nickbiso/Keras-Class-Activation-Map/blob/master/Class%20Activation%20Map(CAM).ipynb) on my model yet the return of `pooled_grads_value,  conv_layer_output_value = iterate([x])` is all zeros for `pooled_grads_value` but the `conv_layer_output_value` has values in it.

this is how i used it:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from keras import backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import keras
import numpy as np
#%%
model_path = "pathto/model.h5"
img_path = "pathto/pic.tif"
output_path = "pathto/output.jpeg"
size = (1000,200)
#%%

model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)

img=mpimg.imread(img_path)
plt.imshow(img)
#%%

from keras.preprocessing import image
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=size)
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

#%%
preds = model.predict(x)

argmax = np.argmax(preds[0])

output = model.output[:, argmax]
#%%
last_conv_layer = model.get_layer( "conv_6_l")
grads = K.gradients(output, last_conv_layer.output)[0]
pooled_grads = K.mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))
iterate = K.function([model.input], [pooled_grads, last_conv_layer.output[0]])
#%%
pooled_grads_value,  conv_layer_output_value = iterate([x])
#%%
for i in range(64):
    conv_layer_output_value[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads_value[i]
#%%
heatmap = np.mean(conv_layer_output_value, axis=-1)
heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap, 0)
#heatmap /= np.max(heatmap)
#%%
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
heatmap = cv2.resize(heatmap, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(heatmap, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
hif = .8
superimposed_img = heatmap * hif + img
cv2.imwrite("pathto/justheatmap.jpeg", heatmap * hif)
#%%
cv2.imwrite(output_path, superimposed_img)
```

my model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), input_shape=(1000, 200, 3), name = "conv_1"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), name="conv_2"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), name="conv_3"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),name="conv_4"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3),name="conv_5"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),name="conv_6_l"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dropout(0.33))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='Adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Does anyone know what the source of my problem is?

I also tried a different aproach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58322147/how-to-generate-cnn-heatmaps-using-built-in-keras-in-tf2-0-tf-keras) using tensorflow.keras.GradientTape() function , yet this gives me an error `module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GradientTape` so I sticked to the first aproach.

I'm using keras V 2.3.1 and tensorflow V 2.1.0 in python.

I also uploaded a [zip-file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1416Ukx0rIkDgBJPzZWRuxwNtyejIAZjT/view?usp=sharing) containing the .h5 file of my model and one picture for testing

Thanks in advance for everyone trying to help!

Hans

Comment: Are you trying to visualize the computed gradients using heatmap?

Comment: Yes, like it is done in the first hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

We can capture Gradients using Keras `Backend` OR Tensorflow `tf.GradientTape()` function. Later we can use these Gradients to visualize as Heatmap. Would like to route you to two SO Answers that have explained on how to capture the gradients and visualize them as Heatmap. These 2 SO Answers would suffice your requirements.

Please refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62243620/visualizing-the-gradients-as-heat-map-in-tensorflow-2/62324263#62324263) for capturing the gradients using Keras `Backend` and also for visualizing the gradients as heat map.

If you are keen on capturing the gradients using the Tensorflow `tf.GradientTape()` function then please refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62285645/14290244) and for visualizing the Gradients as heatmap you can use the same code mentioned in the earlier answer.